# Why Java doesn't throw exception when decoding bytes to string failed?

Tags: java, file-encodings

If there is some exception when decoding failed, then we can try to detect the file encoding by one by one trying.

But I didn't found a way which will throw some exception like 'UnicodeDecodeError' in python, is there some specific reason?

PS: the decoding process is failed when some bytes maps to undefined char, since most of the encoding scheme left some unencoded redundancy codes.

PPS: I ask this question because I think it is a design problem. I'm not having problem about encoding. But when I want to write some code to auto detect the file encoding just like what Vim (the text editor) does, I find that this design makes things hard.

Comment: How do you know it failed? What is the indication?

Comment: the decoding process is failed when some bytes maps to undefined char, since most of the encoding scheme left some unencoded redundancy codes.

Answer (score 0):

Any sequence of bytes would only make sense to you as a String if they make sense as character stream which is relevant to your use case.

What do you expect Java to do when the interpretation is not suitable to your use case?
You will see "garbage" output. But the decoding didn't technically fail. Did it? So, it can't really throw any exception.

Your specified encoding is not probably the one compatible.

Comment: I ask this question because I think it is a design problem. I'm not having problem about encoding. But when I want to write some code to auto detect the file encoding just like what Vim (the text editor) does, I find that this design makes things hard.

Comment: @luochen1990 Use the [Apche Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) library. It does encoding detection for you.